# Pushing order details from a crm (in this case retool) into Xero via api

Tags: xero-api, retool

The goal is to transfer orders from a retool crm into Xero. The target data might be {{orders_view.selectedRow}} from a retool app.
How is the transfer of data from a retool environment to xero handled with xero api?

I've been struggling to find the right docs on this. Would appreciate any advice.